# Getting wrong late fee

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of a problem calculating a late fee in PHP. When I pay the amount before the due date it still calculates the late fee. In this code, I've used `$invoicedate` as the due date.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$invoicedate = strtotime("2016-04-30");
$TodayDate = strtotime('2016-03-02');
$timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - $invoicedate);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);
$noOfdaysToCheck ="15";
$Fees ="1000";

if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){

  $Interval = $numberDays/$noOfdaysToCheck;

  for($i=1;$i<=$Interval;$i++){
    $late = (1 / 100) * $Fees;
    $Fees =  FeesCalc($Fees);
  }

}

$Fees = number_format($Fees, 2, '.', '');
echo $Fees;
echo '<br />';
echo $numberDays;

function FeesCalc($Fees){
  $late = (1 / 100) * $Fees;
  return $TotalFees = $late+$Fees;
}

?>
```

Comment: The for loop that you have does not make much sense. What exactly are you trying to do with that ?

Comment: What is the use of `$late` variable in the for loop ?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to add 1% to a total number from my DB every 15 days. If my balance today is 1000 and I have not paid it in 15 days, it adds 1%, but if I don't pay it in 30 days, it adds 1% on top of the first 15 days late fee.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are using `abs` function.
The difference between "today" date (2016-03-02) and "invoice" date (2016-04-30) is less than `-15` which absolute value is greater than 15.

You should remove this function call and check if `$timeDiff` is positive. Positive value would mean that invoice has not been paid in time and fee should be calculated. Negative or zero means that invoice has been paid in time.

You also should consider using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for keeping dates and times and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for time intervals operations to make your code more readable. Note that these classes provide easy ways to compare and operate on time values.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few logic problem.

Try this:

```
<?php 

$invoicedate = strtotime("2016-04-30");
$TodayDate = strtotime('2016-03-02');
$timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - $invoicedate);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);
$noOfdaysToCheck ="15";
$Fees ="1000";

if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){

  $Interval = $numberDays/$noOfdaysToCheck;

    $Fees =  FeesCalc($Fees,$Interval);

}

$Fees = number_format($Fees, 2, '.', '');
echo $Fees;
echo '<br />';
echo $numberDays;

function FeesCalc($Fees, $days){
  $late = ($days / 100) * $Fees;
  return ($late+$Fees);
}

?>
```